# How do.call orders rows of a data.frame?

Tags: r, do.call

I'm translating an R code to Python. There is a do.call command on a data.frame that orders its rows. How this is done confuses me.

```
signary = matrix(c( 1, 1, 1,-1,-1,-1,
                    0, 0, 0, 1,-1, 0,
                    0, 1,-1, 0, 0, 0,
                    1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 1,-1),
                 ncol=5)

do.call('order', as.data.frame(signary))

[1] 5 6 4 3 1 2
```

How is done the ordering of the rows?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you determining the order?

Comment: The signary matrix is a kind of matrix that passes through the do.call(...) command. Columns in this matrix can be interchanged, but not rows. The ranks given by the do.call(...) command is used to order plot labels. I'm not sure if it answers your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will order the rows by the first column, then the second, then the third. If you re-index by the result of do.call, you get

```
ii<-do.call('order', as.data.frame(signary))
signary[ii,]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   -1   -1    0    0    1
# [2,]   -1    0    0    0   -1
# [3,]   -1    1    0    0    1
# [4,]    1    0   -1   -1    0
# [5,]    1    0    0    1    0
# [6,]    1    0    1   -1    0
```

So first you order by column one, breaking ties with column 2, breaking ties with column 3, etc.

The statement is equivalent to

```
ii<-order(signary[,1], signary[,2], signary[,3], signary[,4], signary[,5])
ii
# [1] 5 6 4 3 1 2
```

Comment: Great. I could find a Python equivalent using pandas sort_index: signary_df = pd.DataFrame(signary); ii = np.array(signary_df.sort_index(by=range(0,signary_df.shape[1]), ascending=True).index)